# Debian Metapackage with version of package from repository

Tags: debian, package, deb

I want to create a debian metapackage with my version of tilda (from my local repository), but I don't have any idea how to do this. I put my metapackage and my version of tilda in my local repository, but I have a problem. How do I specify that the tilda package should be installed from my repository? (That it's must be a metapackage because I want to add some more dependencies in future).

Comment: What is "ns-control"?

Comment: file generated by equivs-build

Comment: Oh, it's used in a lot of `equivs` examples, but the actual file name can be anything, really. For the record, `equivs-control` generates a boilerplate version of this file (but it's easy to write one from scratch as well); `equivs-build` only reads it.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that.. I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward way for a package to affect what gets installed on a system before it is itself installed. The common ways to manage installation preferences is by either *(a)* making sure the custom package has a version number which is higher than the regular package's, or *(b)* for the admin to install a [pin](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning) on the preferred repo. I would go with the former because it's simple and intuitive, and only requires the admin to enable your repo.

There is no particular reason for you to create a separate metapackage if you are building your own custom version of the tilda package anyway. Just add the other packages you want to pull in to the `Depends:` part of the package's `debian/control` file.

Comment: That give me a eveything what I want to know. Thanks:)!
I have another question, that is possible to add to metapackage information about removing some program ? (I don't want one program, so I want to create a metapackage to uninstall them or with information about conflict that's possible ? )

Comment: Add `Conflicts:` but generally, create a new question; almost nobody will see a question in a comment to an answer.